# How to get questions, under a tag, which have at least one answer with 10+ votes?

Tags: support, api, questions

I want to get all the questions under a tag which has at least one answer with 10 or more votes.

I searched the [Advanced Search documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) and searched Py-StackExchange's documentation, but I could not find suitable parameters.

Comment: I don't know how to do this via the API, but [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/705383) returns the results you want.

Comment: Thank you very much @Glorfindel. I wanted some way to get the results. I'm happy with your comment.  If you can move your comment to answers section, i will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The API is very poor for finding results based on *answer* criteria, despite numerous feature requests.

You can't do this with any of the `/answers` routes, and the `/search` routes return questions only, and don't provide the search criteria needed.

Your most accurate results can be had with SEDE, like [the query Glorfindel provided](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/705383), but this lags by a week and is not automatable.
[BigQuery allows you to automate queries to the data dump](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/15/you-can-now-play-with-stack-overflow-data-on-googles-bigquery/), but this data is only updated every quarter.

---

**You can *almost* do this in the API** with [the `/search/advanced` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) and a judicious use of the `q` parameter.

For example this API query:
          [/2.2/search/advanced?q=is:answer score:10&tagged=angularjs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#q=is%3Aanswer%20score%3A10&tagged=angularjs&filter=!)IMBoe)PKTzgbG6c1tRkQy(Q)4JJLbguDL2O&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

Returns all *questions*, tagged *angularjs*, that have one or more answers scoring 10 or greater.

It is roughly equivalent to [this advanced search on the live website](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangularjs%5D%20is%3Aanswer%20score%3A10), ***except*** that the website returns *answers* and the API returns *questions*.  Note that questions often have several answers scoring more than 10. (And qualifying questions usually have other lower-scoring answers too.)

The API results are like:

```js
{
    "tags": ["angularjs", "angular-ui-router"],
    "answers": [ {
            "owner": {"display_name": "apohl"},
            "is_accepted": true,
            "score": 4,
            "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233251/default-route-for-angular-ui-router/22235960#22235960"
        }, {
            "owner": {"display_name": "nottinhill"},
            "is_accepted": false,
            "score": 15,
            "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233251/default-route-for-angular-ui-router/27435414#27435414"
        }, {
            "owner": {"display_name": "Jorge Armando Palm"},
            "is_accepted": false,
            "score": 6,
            "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233251/default-route-for-angular-ui-router/29166806#29166806"
        },
        etc...
    ],
    "is_answered": true,
    "view_count": 38211,
    "answer_count": 6,
    "score": 16,
    "last_activity_date": 1509428733,
    "creation_date": 1394131433,
    "question_id": 22233251,
    "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233251/default-route-for-angular-ui-router",
    "title": "Default route for angular ui router"
} ],
... More questions...
```

That is, for each qualifying question, all of its answers are listed.

**HOWEVER**, this approach **also restricts the results to questions that have at least 10 upvotes.**  So it's not exactly what you want, but most questions that a 10-score answer, tend to have 10+ votes too, and vice-versa.